# Condition Statement (For, If, Elif and else)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

In the python script that I'm doing now is:

I have 2 columns:

1. Amount (Cash books)
2. Amount (Bank records)

What I am doing is:

1. Find their difference and add to 'DIFFERENCE' column for comparison of their values
2. Adding remarks under 'REMARKS' column.

here are the remarks to be listed:

a. MATCHED if DIFFERENCE = 0

b. OVER-RECORDING if DIFFERENCE > 0 but not equal to the  minuend

c. NOT YET ENCASHED if DIFFERENCE > 0 and equal to the minuend (or subtrahend is 0)

d. UNDER-RECORDING if DIFFERENCE < 0 but not equal to the subtrahend

e. UNRECORDED if DIFFERENCE < 0 and equal to the subtrahend (or minuend is 0)

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.read_csv('DB3-BankRecon.csv',encoding='latin-1', index_col= False, thousands= ',',decimal=b'.') #df3 because this is the 3rd dataframe
amount1, amount2 = df3[' AMOUNT (Cash books)'], df3[' AMOUNT (Bank Records)']
diff = amount1 - amount2
df3['DIFFERENCE'] = diff #Created 'DIFFERENCE' column and save the difference
df3['REMARKS'] = '' #REMARKS column

for row in diff: #rows in DIFFERENCE column
    for cashrow in amount1: #rows in AMOUNT (Cash books)
        for bankrow in amount2: #rows in AMOUNT (Bank Records)
            try:
                if row != 0:
                    if row > 0:
                        if row < cashrow:
                            df3['REMARKS'] = 'Over-Recording'
                        else:
                            df3['REMARKS'] = 'Not yet encashed'
                    elif row < 0:
                        if abs(row) < bankrow:
                            df3['REMARKS'] = 'Under-Recording'
                        else:
                            df3['REMARKS'] = 'Unrecorded' 
                else: # row == 0
                    df3['REMARKS'] = 'Matched'
            except:
                print('Error')

df3.to_csv('Try.csv', index=False)
```

every time I run the results in VS code, everything is fine (especially the conditions)

but when I add the DIFFERENCES results and the REMARKS results to dataframe, all the values of REMARKS becomes 'MATCHED' even they're not.

[Here's the screenshot of the csv file][1]

How to solve this?

just a month in Python.

Thanks in advance :)

#### UPDATE: (Thanks for the responses :) )

Here's the sample input:(csv file opened in notepad)

---

```
AMOUNT(Cash books),AMOUNT(Bank Records)
1065.00,1065.00
1056.40,1056.40
1038.60,1033.60
1027.98,1072.98
1027.00,0.00
0.00,1015.44
1001.66,1001.66
1001.50,1001.50
```

---

Expected output

```
AMOUNT (Cash books) | AMOUNT (Bank Records) | DIFFERENCE | REMARKS

     1065.00        |        1065.00        |      0.00  | Matched
     1056.40        |        1056.40        |      0.00  | Matched
     1038.60        |        1033.60        |      5.00  | Over-Recording
     1027.98        |        1072.98        |    -45.00  | Under-Recording
     1027.00        |           0.00        |  1,027.00  | Not yet encashed
        0.00        |        1015.44        | -1,015.44  | Unrecorded
     1001.66        |        1001.66        |      0.00  | Matched
     1001.50        |        1001.50        |      0.00  | Matched
```

Note: When I run the code in the editor without saving it to csv file, I get the expected REMARKS output. but when I'm trying to save it to the dataframe and to the file, it all results to 'MATCHED'.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Post your input & expected out put as text. We cannot copy the image & create the dataframe.

Comment: Kindly provide a minimally workable data sample to reproduce your error/problem.